# Skip code part in MEX compilation

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a C file that is compiled for both a console application and a MATLAB MEX file. I wish to exclude some parts of the code when compiled for MEX. Is there a `definition` I can check during MEX compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mex files are required to have the preprocessor symbol `MATLAB_MEX_FILE` defined.